# Make an 'Info' item show in the build list

Tags: c#, asp.net, build

Is there any way to annotate sections of my code to generate out a 'Messages' item when building? There are some spots in my code I want to mark as things to get changed in an upcoming revision.

Any tools or features that would give me something similar to this? I was thinking Bookmarks, but I've found them to be kind of clunky in VS2010.

[image: Message Item]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set comments in your code like this:

```
//TODO: Make much better someday (probably never)
if (i != null)
{
    this.DoSomething();
}
```

The `//TODO:` comment is a built-in extension of Visual Studio and the given comment is shown in the "Task List"-Control of the IDE.
With a double click on the item in the "Task List" you can jump to the spot in your code where the comment is set.

Read this article for further information: [How to: Create Task List Comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zce12xx2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Nice! I think that will work out perfectly! Bookmarks are nice for tagging spots in the code to jump around but I would rather have it have a specific description attached to it. I think that's exactly the solution I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Are you planning on having these notifications in Visual Studio, or do you want them to be a part of an automated or command-line build process?

If it's the former, Jan P.'s answer is a good place to start, showing you how to interface with Visual Studio's Task List interface.

If it's the latter, and you really want a line that shows up in your build output, you can *kind of* do that using C#'s [Preprocessor Directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), specifically the #warning directive. That will output a *warning*, however, and I don't know of a way to output an *info* line. This is how it's done:

```
  public void Test()
    {
#warning This is silly.
    }
```

and this is the result in VS:

[image]

Comment: It would be nice to have them in the 'Messages' pane just as a one-off notice when building. Not part of any automated builds or tasks. Thanks for the suggestion though!